# Media-attachment crops image in ios 10 notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ios10

**iOS10** notifications allow us to add images as **media-attachments** to them.
Unfortunately, I haven't found any good way to control attachment's appearance inside the notification.

For example, I'm adding as attachment this image:
[image]

And it shows as:

[image]

**I'm passing square-images and want to avoid image-crop** (as you can see one ear of cat has been cut).

I'm sending notifcation (as a local one) via this snippet:

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Test notification"
    content.body = "Test notification"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myNotificationCategory"

    let attachement = try! UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "image",
                                                                url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cat", withExtension: "png")!,
                                                                options: nil)

    content.attachments = [ attachement ]
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
        if (error != nil){
        }
    }
```

**So the questions are**:

- Can I avoid image crop? (If not - how to remove image at all?)
- Bonus question: is there a way to show 2 media-attachments in one notification (while it's collapsed)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with the `UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailClippingRectKey` to put in the option parameter to the `UNNotificationAttachment` creation method? See the doc for more info.

Comment: @Larme thanks for the comment! Doc looks promising, but in the real life never managed to make it work (Xcode-beta5, iOS 10 beta 5). Have you tried it?

Comment: I up-voted because of the cat. (and good question of course).

Answer (score 4):

You should - as [@larme comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086878/media-attachment-crops-image-in-ios-10-notification#comment65525852_39086878) - be able to use [UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailClippingRectKey](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationattachmentoptionsthumbnailclippingrectkey). However, there seems to be a bug there somewhere:

- https://openradar.appspot.com/27708976?
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/154320#154320

Answer (score 0):

I return to this very old thread… The solution I have found (not gorgeous !), is to create another image (in resource) with a square format. Because the rect is in fact a square that clips the original.